# How do I get VS Code on a Mac setup for Azure functions and F#?

Tags: azure, f#, visual-studio-code

According to the [editor prelude section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-fsharp#editor-prelude) of using F# with Azure Functions, one should add the following to the top of their code:

```
#if !COMPILED
#I "../../bin/Binaries/WebJobs.Script.Host"
#r "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.dll"
#endif
```

I'm working on a Mac with VS Code and the Ionide-fsharp extension.

My question is: how can I get VS Code to be aware of the libraries that are included in Azure Functions?

Edit: The error that I'm getting is `The search directory '/Users/martimatix/Projects/sandbox/fsharp_test/../../bin/Binaries/WebJobs.Script.Host' could not be found`

Comment: You could put https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs/ in your `paket.dependencies`, then point the `#I` directive at the appropriate directory in your `packages` directory while you're developing. When you're ready to deploy, switch the `#I` to the one from the Azure documentation. **NOTE**: I haven't done this myself, so I don't know if it would work, but it seems like it might.